# How to use filereader or filesystem to reload a txt file continuously

Tags: javascript, filesystems

I am currently developing chrome extension.
Right now I need to reload a txt file in local disk and show the file content on the screen.
I actually created a thread to do that, but just found the txt file won't be reloaded again after changing the content in the txt file.

In the first time I used chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry + fileread to do that.
It will prompt a Window for user to choose a file.
After this, I don't want to let use choose file again.

Is it possible to let browser keep reloading the txt file without prompt a Window for user to choose a file. thanks a lot

```
  function executeAsync(func) {
    setTimeout(func, 0);
  }

  executeAsync(function() {
     for (var i = 0 ; i < 200; i++) {

       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onloadend = function(e) {
         str_buf = this.result;
         var dump = str_buf.split('\n');
       }
       console.log ("test\n");

       reader.readAsText(registerFile);//registerFile is from chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath from another code
     }

  });
```

Comment: No, it is not possible, JS can access files selected by user only.

Comment: I will let use to select file at the first time. just want to do sync file without prompting a window next time.
is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to keep the reference to the file alive? Use outer scope instead of declaring new reader every time.

Comment: I am finally able to do it. Just to put the file in the directory same with the chrome extension and use ajax to read it.
thanks.